# How can I throttle Fine Uploader and still display queued uploads?

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

My endpoint for Fine Uploader is on a server that limits the number of requests per second. Throttling uploads can be achieved using **maxConnections: 1** and returning a promise in **onValidate** that resolves when at least X time has passed since the last **onValidate** call.

The problem is that since the throttle is in the **onValidate** callback, the uploads do not display in the queue because they have not yet been validated.

The documentation states that the following callbacks support promises:

- onCancel
- onCredentialsExpired
- onPasteReceived
- onSubmit
- onSubmitDelete
- onValidate
- onValidateBatch

Using **onSubmit** with the exact same code does not throttle the uploads, as it seems to be called at the time the file is added. Unfortunately, none of the other callbacks seem like an appropriate time to achieve the desired results.

Is there a way to achieve this type of throttle and still display queued uploads?

Here's what my current solution looks like:

```js
/************************** file 1 **************************/
angular
.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myController', [
    '$scope',
    '$q',
function(
    $scope,
    $q
){
    var lastUploadTime = false;
    $scope.throttledUpload = function(throttle){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var elapsedTime = Date.now() - lastUploadTime;
        var delay = 0;
        if(elapsedTime <= throttle){
            delay = throttle - elapsedTime;
        }
        setTimeout(function(){
            lastUploadTime = Date.now();
            deferred.resolve();
        }, delay);

        return deferred.promise;
    };
}]);

/************************** file 2 **************************/
var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
    element: document.getElementById('file-uploader'),
    maxConnections: 1,
    request: {
        endpoint: 'upload.php'
    },
    retry: {
        enableAuto: true
    },
    callbacks: {
        onStatusChange: function(){
            // omitted for brevity, returns nothing
        },
        onValidate: function(){
            // this works, but will not work if instead passed as onSubmit
            return angular
                .element('#photo-galleries-controller')
                .scope()
                .throttledUpload(400);
        },
        onComplete: function(){
            // omitted for brevity, returns nothing
        }
    }
});
```

There's an example at https://plnkr.co/edit/14BaZj5cBbX1FYMPpne9?p=preview, however the server does not limit requests for this demo.

** **Edit** **

There does indeed seem to be a difference in how onValidate and onSubmit process promises.

The onSubmit() callback will wait for the promise to be resolved before uploading that file, but dropping many files on the UI will cause all of their onSubmit() callbacks to happen immediately. Adding a two second delay via onSubmit() will cause a batch of files to all be uploaded at (roughly) the same time, but two seconds after they are dropped on the UI.

The onValidate() callback differs in that they are processed serially. Returning a promise from an onValidate() callback causes the next file's validation to be deferred as well. Adding a two second delay via onValidate() will cause a batch of files to be uploaded with (roughly) two seconds in between each start of upload.

Here is the console output showing the above. The only difference between these two is in which callback the promise is returned. The other callback returns nothing (undefined).

**onSubmit():**
`2016-09-28 16:50:08.918 onValidate()
2016-09-28 16:50:08.927 onSubmit()
2016-09-28 16:50:08.929 -- delaying for 0ms
2016-09-28 16:50:08.938 onValidate()
2016-09-28 16:50:08.939 onSubmit()
2016-09-28 16:50:08.940 -- delaying for 1997ms
2016-09-28 16:50:08.951 onUpload()
2016-09-28 16:50:08.956 onValidate()
2016-09-28 16:50:08.956 onSubmit()
2016-09-28 16:50:08.958 -- delaying for 1980ms
2016-09-28 16:50:08.990 onValidate()
2016-09-28 16:50:08.991 onSubmit()
2016-09-28 16:50:08.994 -- delaying for 1943ms
2016-09-28 16:50:09.009 onValidate()
2016-09-28 16:50:09.010 onSubmit()
2016-09-28 16:50:09.011 -- delaying for 1926ms
2016-09-28 16:50:09.033 onComplete()
2016-09-28 16:50:10.947 onUpload()
2016-09-28 16:50:11.029 onComplete()
2016-09-28 16:50:11.032 onUpload()
2016-09-28 16:50:11.229 onComplete()
2016-09-28 16:50:11.231 onUpload()
2016-09-28 16:50:11.291 onComplete()
2016-09-28 16:50:11.293 onUpload()
2016-09-28 16:50:11.342 onComplete()`

**onValidate():**
`2016-09-28 16:56:11.002 onValidate()
2016-09-28 16:56:11.009 -- delaying for 0ms
2016-09-28 16:56:11.021 onSubmit()
2016-09-28 16:56:11.045 onUpload()
2016-09-28 16:56:11.095 onValidate()
2016-09-28 16:56:11.096 -- delaying for 1919ms
2016-09-28 16:56:11.142 onComplete()
2016-09-28 16:56:13.021 onSubmit()
2016-09-28 16:56:13.029 onUpload()
2016-09-28 16:56:13.039 onValidate()
2016-09-28 16:56:13.040 -- delaying for 1975ms
2016-09-28 16:56:13.245 onComplete()
2016-09-28 16:56:15.019 onSubmit()
2016-09-28 16:56:15.053 onUpload()
2016-09-28 16:56:15.090 onValidate()
2016-09-28 16:56:15.091 -- delaying for 1924ms
2016-09-28 16:56:15.419 onComplete()
2016-09-28 16:56:17.020 onSubmit()
2016-09-28 16:56:17.063 onUpload()
2016-09-28 16:56:17.121 onValidate()
2016-09-28 16:56:17.122 -- delaying for 1894ms
2016-09-28 16:56:17.131 onComplete()
2016-09-28 16:56:19.021 onSubmit()
2016-09-28 16:56:19.080 onUpload()
2016-09-28 16:56:19.236 onComplete()`

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: "Using onSubmit with the exact same code does not throttle the uploads, as it seems to be called at the time the file is added." I don't understand this. The file will not be uploaded until your promise returned from onSubmit is resolved.

Comment: I *think* what might be happening is that I'm dropping a bunch of images and onValidate processes promises serially, while onSubmit does not. I've looked at fine-uploader.core.js but there's a lot to follow to understand the differences.

Comment: @RayNicholus - thanks for your help Ray. I should be able to solve this by resolving each promise in onComplete().

Comment: Unfortunately, deferring in onSubmit() and resolving the last deferred upload in onComplete() causes the same problem - the file is not displayed in the upload queue. I'm going to simply allow uploads to process without throttling and let the retry functionality handle any that fail due to the server's request limit. While this is not ideal, it does still function and is an edge case at this time.